# How do you use COUNTIF function to compare a column of text to a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a column of data on another worksheet where all the dates are saved as text. On this worksheet I need to count the number dates between two dates where the dates I'm comparing are saved as dates.
`A1` is the date I'm comparing it to and `A` would be the column of data on the other worksheet.
I can use `=IF(DATEVALUE(AnotherWorkSheet!A1)>A1, true)` and it will correctly return true or false.

I am attempting to use

```
=COUNTIFS(AnotherWorkSheet!A:A, ">=" & A1, AnotherWorkSheet!A:A, "<=" & B1)
```

which gives 0 due to the column being full of text.

```
=COUNTIFS(DATEVALUE(AnotherWorkSheet!A:A), ">=" & A1, DATEVALUE(AnotherWorkSheet!A:A), "<=" & B1)
```

doesn't work.

Basically I need a function that will convert a column of text dates into dates. I am not allowed to change the formatting of the dates or create other cells.

Comment: When you state that you cannot change formatting or create other cells, is that just on `AnotherWorkSheet`?  If you can add a column to the sheet that contains you formula, you could put a reference to your dates, such as `=DATEVALUE(AnotherWorkSheet!A1)` and drag it down. Then substitute that column reference for the `AnotherWorkSheet!A:A` in your `COUNTIFS` formula.

Comment: Are you sure DATEVALUE is working for you? What is the format of you dates in the string?  If date value does not work, there is potential to pull the date string apart and convert it another way to a date.  Big ugly formula but it can work.